# Oracle Service Bus XPath Implementation

Tags: xquery, osb, oracle-service-bus

I'm using Oracle Service Bus 11g Release 1 (11.1.1.3) and have a problem with it's XPath Implementation.

A XQuery-Resource contains a simple XPath Axes Location Path:

```
preceding::SomeElement
```

Oracle says it should work: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14571_01/doc.1111/e15867/xquery.htm#i1106823

> The Oracle Service Bus XQuery engine fully supports all of the language features that are described in the World Wide Web (W3C) specification for XQuery with one exception: modules. For more information about the XQuery 1.0 and XPath 2.0 functions and operators >(W3C Working Draft 23 July 2004), see the following URL: http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/WD-xpath-functions-20040723/

.. but it doesn't:

> Error occurred while executing XQuery: {bea-err}SYS001: This functionality has not been implemented (sorry)

Answer (score 1):

OSB 12c supports XQuery 1.0 including library modules and the preceding axis.

http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery/
http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/osb/develop/osb-xquery.htm

Comment: Where do you get this information from? [link](http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/osb/develop/osb-xquery.htm#A1212537) says "[...]XQuery with one exception: modules"

Comment: The documentation must be out of date.  If you try 12c, you will see that it is supported.